# Trying to access Substrate node through substrate-front-end-template Error { "isTrusted": true }

Tags: ubuntu, browser, yarnpkg, substrate

I am trying to access the substrate-front-end-template through my browser window but I get the following error. I'm using a VPS with Ubuntu 20.04
This is my result
I start my node with this.

./target/release/node-template --dev --unsafe-ws-external --rpc-cors all  --rpc-external --rpc-methods=Unsafe

I then start yarn in the substrate-front-end-template directory.

[Yarn Started](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gJOl.png)

I try connecting using http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8000/substrate-front-end-template

[Trying to connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PM0Q1.png)

In my browser I get.
[Using port 8000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHtUA.png)

or
[9944](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOo8J.png)

I have changed the \root\substrate-front-end-template\src\config\development.json to "PROVIDER_SOCKET": "ws://xxx.xxx.xxx:9944" (Here was the issue.)

If anyone can help I would be eternally grateful.

Update:
all sorted it was my own silly fault. In file root\substrate-front-end-template\src\config\development.json I didnt put the full IP address of my server in. I feel very silly. Thanks to anyone that helped.

Comment: Are you certain your front-end-template can see your node?

Please look at the browser's developer console for any errors.

Answer (score 2):

u can try add

--unsafe-ws-external --rpc-cors all

to your node-template args.

Comment: tried that mate but no change unfortunately. Thanks for your help though.